# Unable to stop python script

Tags: python

Recently i downloaded a python code to automate some stuff in a game while i do errands. Problem is, i can't stop the script. First of all i copy pasted the script into a txt file then changed it to py file, which for some reason didn't want to start. After that i changed it to pyw and it worked, but, as i mentioned in the title i can't stop it. It's not in the task manager, after i run the script nothing even opens. I have to restart my PC to stop it from running over and over. Ctrl + Break didn't work, Ctrl + C also didn't work. At first i wanted to start it through the python executable not the script itself but after looking and looking all over i couldn't find anything about how to start a python script. Those that i did find didn't work. So how am i supposed to do?

Comment: Could you please post the exact steps that you followed, the platform you are running on, how you are executing the script etc? Also please tage a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You're not giving us any information about the script, where you got from, how does it interact with your computer, etc. How is anyone supposed to know what's wrong. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask?utm_source=Iterable&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=gen-welcome-email&utm_content=aug18)

Comment: can you post the script?

Comment: While this is definitely about "a programming tool", I'm not sure if we can support people who are not "professional and enthusiastic programmers".

Comment: Stack Overflow is a website for developing software. Downloading and using third party software is not covered.

Comment: I'm on Windows, and i did exactly what i said, i have a pyw script file that when i launch it, it starts in the background, can't find it through the task manager or anything, i don't know what else to say that is literally what i did. As for the script it's just a simple script that pushes keys.

Comment: You could at least have stopped the process using the task manager instead of restarting the PC.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, i thought i could ask my question here since whenever i search about python questions i get redirected here.

Comment: As i said it's not in the task manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the program : `taskkill /F /IM pythonw.exe`

The reason nothing opened when you clicked on the file with a `.pyw` extension is because `.pyw` files run in the background when you open them from file explorer. If you want a window to open use the `.py` extension.

To start it from the command line just navigate to the directory through command prompt or powershell and run `python yourscript.py`.

Comment: But why didn't the script start when i tried it as a py file?